# How to call Controller using in AJAX in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to call ajax in when a customer clicks on place order button. 
If a user clicks place order button, that should call js from there it should call Controller?
How to write Controller for that JS  in the checkout page?
Can Anyone Help me?
Urgent.
I don't have an idea where to write controller and return to JS.

Comment: describe your requirement in some more detail. You want to know how to overide place order button? or you want to know how to call controller action from AJAX?